# How add flex application to IIS in windows 7?

Tags: apache-flex, iis, flex4, flex4.5

I have developed a flex application .I need to host that application in IIS (Internet Information Services ) . I tried few ways but did not work. Guys can you give me a good reference or steps to host application in IIS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow the [following](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831515.aspx) steps. Because the flex is static content, you can drop the content from the export release build into the root of the folder you just created on the server. and access it through browser